# Dash to Panel for Unity in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, launcher

Is there any option which work like Dash to Panel for 16.04 with Unity ? ie, removing top bar completely and give a single taskbar. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No unfortunately not for Ubuntu 16.04 but you can always wait for 18.04 LTS to come out and then upgrade.